# Best practice to place a function which executes automatically on each page call

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, master-pages

I have a scenario as follows,

I'm having an application in that i need to execute a function, which needs to be executed before page load of each pages. even if i add a new page, the function needs to be execute with out copying that function into the new page.

Please guide me Best practice to place the function in an application, so that it will work as i stated.

If your answer is master page, then in Master page which event is the best place to write the function code?

The process of the function is to call DAL class and get data from database , get the page name and need to do some login based on the page name.

Thanks and regards

Comment: Would you not be better off caching this data instead?

Comment: even if am caching the data, i need to do some logic with the data and the Page name.

Comment: WebForms or MVC?  What logic do you need to perform (there may be better ways to do what you want to do).  You want to process "login" based on the page name?  What security model are you implementing?

Comment: Both in Asp.net Webform and in MVC. i would check for the page name in the data and if its there i will allow the user to access the page or else i will redirect the user to authentication page.

Comment: Stick with MVC, and use http://asp.net/identity.  You can then decorate the controller actions with the `[Authorize]` attribute and restrict views/pages to specific users/roles.  No logic required to be written by you to hit the DB and check page names (which sounds very fragile)

Comment: @Sindhu  what @brendan suggestted looks clean, even in webform the approch you are asking also can be achievable, like i am assuming you are having master page in web forms in that page load you need to check page name like this  `Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains(("pagename.aspx").ToLower())` and if its true do your logic , in this approach you need to write a lot of code and logic

Comment: Hi Brendan thank you for your answer, As I'm currently working in Asp.net Web forms, i need to know the best practice in web forms too, Could you please guide me on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider using custom HttpModule

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx

or in Global.asax you can hook up desired event in Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute:

```
void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;

            if (context.Handler is Page)
            {
                Page page = (Page)context.Handler;
                page.Load += ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, does this piece of code executes for every requests? my scenario is to call a function which executes only once before every page load. by checking the page and redirecting based on authentication.

Comment: Every time the page loads is a page request

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will work on this and will get to you for further queries.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVC, then a possible approach could be to make a call in _Layout page.